# Resetting cached query with cachedwithin

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Inside a `cffunction` I have a query that I want to long cache by setting the `cachedwitin` to a big value.  However, I also want to clear that cache under a few circumstances.

I've done this in a number of places, but in one of them the cache is never updated and I always get the original value if I ask it to give me the cached value.

The [cfquery documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fae.html) states:

> To use cached data, the current query must use the same SQL statement, data source, query name, user name, and password.

This is the case with the query, since it's a single sql statement with no non-sql except the `cfqueryparam`; datasource and query name don't change and username and password are not specified.

The relevant code is:

```
<!--- Long cache the query since the values rarely change, but allow the cache to be cleared. --->
<cfif Arguments.ClearCache EQ false>
    <cfset local.CachedWithin = CreateTimeSpan(7,0,0,0)>
<cfelse>
    <cfset local.CachedWithin = CreateTimeSpan(0,0,0,-1)>
</cfif>

<cfquery name="local.qryName" datasource="#Variables.DSN#" cachedwithin="#local.CachedWithin#">
    SELECT
        [User].[Name]
    FROM
        [User]
    WHERE
        [User].[UserID] = <cfqueryparam value="#Arguments.UserID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
</cfquery>
```

Why does this work in other places, but not here?

Comment: Coldfusion is bizarre in the way it handles cache durations. Often caching a value for a `CreateTimeSpan(0,0,0,0)` (or possibly less) does absolutely nothing. One would expect it to not cache the query or clear the query from the cache, but that is what it does.

Comment: @Nucleon do you experience issues with the above code (with the below data type fix) not clearing the cache? I've been using this method for a long time and the only time there are issues is when the "sameness" criteria aren't met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an additional "sameness" requirement for cached queries that isn't mentioned in the documentation.  That note should end with:

> ... password, and underlying data types of any cfqueryparam values.

Change your code so that the `Arguments.UserID` is forced to a data type.  In your case this can be accomplished by putting the following code before the cfquery:

```
<!--- Make sure data types used in query are consistent --->
<cfset local.UserID = Int(Arguments.UserID)>
```

and change the `cfqueryparam` value to `value="#local.UserID#"`.

I've phrased the above as an omission in the documentation, but I suspect it's a bug in CF9 instead.